# how can I add different activities to PagerView?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

How can I add three different layout to ViewPagers including their activities. One of these layout is ListView.

Comment: Go Ahead and move these Activities into [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: It doesn't work. One activity is calculator and other is ListFragment extends baseAdapter

Comment: You cannor keep using those ,you have to extend f fragment

Comment: Just made them fragment (already said). Also, you can add your code so one can check it out and pass you the working/needed one.

Answer (score 1):

The ViewPager works with fragments instead of activities, you can find enough information and examples in Android's documentation [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and [ViewPager Samples](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have given one example of fragment below. you need to make a class, for each fragment, and each of it will have individual layout file.
and yes, you can start an activity from your fragment, as well as create new fragment to represent your information by clicking on list or items in fragment.

Fragment have its own life cycle. You can add, ListView in your fragment as well, you need to extend your fragment to ListFragment.
plus, when you add layout to your class with ListFragment,
Make sure, to add ListView with id as "@android:id/list" otherwise, your application will crash.

For example,
In layout, you need to add this listView with Id of list as i said above,

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="364dp"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
```

and your fragment would be

```
public class FragmentA extends ListFragment {

String[] list_items;

public FragmentA(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false); //this layout R.layout.fragment_a would be the layout will be presented on your fragment. 

    return view;
}
```

i have created array, which you can get the source from String.xml file.
if you need more detailed information, here is the link of video, that might help you to understand it better
[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8l77X0H6SH0).

Comment: but I extends Fragment in order to use switch function for action bar. I can't c @hange to listFragment

Comment: why do you want to use switch function for actionbar?